# Indexing Large Files in Assets

Tags: assets, index

I uploaded a couple mp4 video files via FTP. One is 3.28GB, the other is 5.53GB. I updated Asset Indexes in Settings, but they are not showing up in Assets. I checked the DB and they do not show up there either. No errors are in the logs concerning them.

Any suggestions on how to get them to appear under Assets?

Comment: If you try with just a small image, does it work?

Comment: Yep. I uploaded a PDF, MP3, and small (3MB) MP4 via FTP. They all indexed fine. Just not the big ones.

Comment: Ok, thanks for checking! Can you access the video via a URL to make sure they successfully uploaded? The size of the file shouldn't matter when indexing the sources.

Comment: Yes. I can access via URL, and permissions are correct. It's the weirdest thing. File size shouldn't matter because only images are downloaded during indexing for thumbnail purposes.

Comment: Any errors being logged in `craft/storage/runtime/logs` or your web server's error logs?

Comment: Nothing in Craft logs about it. Nothing concerning Craft activity in the server logs.